# Redraw CGPath from different starting point

Tags: sprite-kit, cgpath

I have a CGPath that represents an ellipse.  I have a sprite that follows the path around the ellipse.  When I stop the follow action, I'd like to take the point of the ellipse I'm on and create a new CGPath, so that I can start moving around the ellipse at a later time from the same point.

Is there a simple way to change the starting point of a CGPath?